# Write JavaScript code inside JavaScript and all in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

I have an ad that will appear when certain conditions, and when that ad appears, the ad will detect the width of the screen and use the ad size that I specify.

I did this using JavaScript, and inside JavaScript and all are in PHP. Problems arise when writing  in `document.write`.

Could you please help me solve this problem.

This is my code:

```
    <?php
    if(!empty($variable1)) {
    echo '
       <script type="text/javascript">
           var swidth = screen.width;

           if (swidth >= 1218) {
               document.write('
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        document.write("
                           <script type='text/javascript'>
                               var adcode = {abcdefg};
                           </script>
                           <script type='text/javascript' src='http://domainname.com/ads.js'></script>
                       ");
                    </script>
                ');
           }
       </script>
   ';
    } else {
        if(!empty($variable2)) {
        echo $ads2;
        } else {}
    }
?>
```

Comment: You should put the code in the question and specify exactly what `problems arise` means.

Comment: what kind of problem are you dealing with?

Answer (score 0):

from line 13 to 22 replace:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'http://domainname.com/ads.js';
$("body").append(script);

var script2 = document.createElement('script');
script2.type = 'text/javascript';
script2.src = 'sc.js';// or url to the script file;
$("body").append(script2);
```

and sc.js:

```
var adcode = {abcdefg};
```

**BUT**

The best way to add JS in PHP:

```
<?php 
// ...
?>

<script src="url_to_script"></script>

<?php 
// ...
?>
```

Manipulations with DOM elements must be defined in JS and not affect PHP.